# pg_stats is huge and slowing PostgreSQL server down.... What do I do?

Tags: postgresql, statistics, postgresql-10

I have two servers running PostgreSQL 10.11 that are configured the same, run on comparable hardware, contain the same databases and (mostly) the same tables.

Various Nagios checks using `check_postgres` check these servers on a routine basis, including one that checks for "bloat".

On one server, this bloat check takes 3-4 seconds.

On the other server, the bloat check takes 24-30 *minutes*. EDIT: It takes 55-60 minutes as of 2020-01-14.

Also, this condition just started like 3 days ago. Before that, the bloat check ran in a reasonable amount of time (less than ~10 seconds) on the now "slow" server.

After additional investigation into the "check_bloat" query used by `check_postgres`, I discovered what I think might be the reason for why it is so much slower on the one server than the other server. The `pg_stats` table contains ~815,000 entries on the slow server. On the "fast" server, it only contains ~45,000 entries. EDIT: Fortysomething days later, the `pg_stats` table contains ~838,000 entries as of 2020-01-14.

What can I do about this? Is there a way to shrink the `pg_stats` (`pg_statistic`) table?

I tried restarting the "slow" server and doing a `vacuum analyze;` on it. No effect.

I tried executing `select pg_stat_reset()` in every database on the "slow" server, but it didn't seem to do anything. (The number of rows in `pg_stats` did not change.)

EDIT: Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT  ns.nspname, tbl.relname, hdr, ma, bs,
        SUM((1-coalesce(null_frac,0))*coalesce(avg_width, 2048)) AS datawidth,
        MAX(coalesce(null_frac,0)) AS maxfracsum,
        hdr+(
          SELECT 1+count(*)/8
          FROM pg_stats s2
          WHERE null_frac<>0 AND s2.schemaname = ns.nspname AND s2.tablename = tbl.relname
        ) AS nullhdr
      FROM pg_attribute att
      JOIN pg_class tbl ON att.attrelid = tbl.oid
      JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid = tbl.relnamespace
      LEFT JOIN pg_stats s ON s.schemaname=ns.nspname
      AND s.tablename = tbl.relname
      AND s.inherited=false
      AND s.attname=att.attname,
      (
        SELECT
          (SELECT current_setting('block_size')::numeric) AS bs,
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SPLIT_PART(v, ' ', 2) FROM '#\"[0-9]+.[0-9]+#\"%' for '#')
              IN ('8.0','8.1','8.2') THEN 27 ELSE 23 END AS hdr,
          CASE WHEN v ~ 'mingw32' OR v ~ '64-bit' THEN 8 ELSE 4 END AS ma
        FROM (SELECT version() AS v) AS foo
      ) AS constants
      WHERE att.attnum > 0 AND tbl.relkind='r'
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

EDIT: Here is the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` on the "slow" server:

```
                                                                                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=1935395.99..4529587255.06 rows=4097995 width=188) (actual time=106609.972..396360.540 rows=96069 loops=1)
   Group Key: ns.nspname, tbl.relname, CASE WHEN ("substring"(split_part(version(), ' '::text, 2), '#\"[0-9]+.[0-9]+#\"%'::text, '#'::text) = ANY ('{8.0,8.1,8.2}'::text[])) THEN 27 ELSE 23 END, CASE WHEN ((version() ~ 'mingw32'::text) OR (version() ~ '64-bit'::text)) THEN 8 ELSE 4 END, $0
   Buffers: shared hit=81434823 read=621336, temp read=340059 written=340054
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1935395.97..2063714.73 rows=4097995 width=176) (actual time=106594.140..263322.505 rows=13304172 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((ns.nspname = s.schemaname) AND (tbl.relname = s.tablename) AND (att.attname = s.attname))
         Buffers: shared hit=6832941 read=331003, temp read=340059 written=340054
         ->  Sort  (cost=1427752.62..1437997.60 rows=4097995 width=192) (actual time=100214.124..113229.530 rows=13304172 loops=1)
               Sort Key: ns.nspname, tbl.relname, att.attname
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2629600kB
               Buffers: shared hit=52022 read=282240, temp read=328700 written=328701
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=15335.36..599474.35 rows=4097995 width=192) (actual time=242.121..56135.695 rows=13304172 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (tbl.relnamespace = ns.oid)
                     Buffers: shared hit=52022 read=282240
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=15246.41..588609.50 rows=4097995 width=132) (actual time=237.991..35301.264 rows=13304172 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (att.attrelid = tbl.oid)
                           Buffers: shared hit=52006 read=282219
                           ->  Seq Scan on pg_attribute att  (cost=0.00..532962.28 rows=15390604 width=68) (actual time=0.004..13225.400 rows=13870158 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (attnum > 0)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 1147617
                                 Buffers: shared hit=42449 read=282219
                           ->  Hash  (cost=14050.06..14050.06 rows=95708 width=72) (actual time=237.495..237.496 rows=96069 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10782kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=9557
                                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_class tbl  (cost=0.00..14050.06 rows=95708 width=72) (actual time=0.005..149.710 rows=96069 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (relkind = 'r'::"char")
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 270863
                                       Buffers: shared hit=9557
                     ->  Hash  (cost=58.42..58.42 rows=2442 width=68) (actual time=4.095..4.096 rows=2393 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 266kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=13 read=21
                           ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace ns  (cost=0.00..58.42 rows=2442 width=68) (actual time=0.007..2.020 rows=2393 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=13 read=21
         ->  Sort  (cost=507643.36..507707.46 rows=25640 width=200) (actual time=6379.663..6409.276 rows=37000 loops=1)
               Sort Key: s.schemaname, s.tablename, s.attname
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 11365kB
               Buffers: shared hit=6780919 read=48763, temp read=11359 written=11353
               ->  Subquery Scan on s  (cost=23845.50..505765.73 rows=25640 width=200) (actual time=1299.167..6301.807 rows=37000 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=6780919 read=48763, temp read=11359 written=11353
                     ->  Gather  (cost=23845.50..505509.33 rows=25640 width=401) (actual time=1299.164..6213.093 rows=37000 loops=1)
                           Workers Planned: 2
                           Workers Launched: 2
                           Buffers: shared hit=6780919 read=48763, temp read=11359 written=11353
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=22845.50..501945.33 rows=10683 width=401) (actual time=1127.147..5861.412 rows=12333 loops=3)
                                 Hash Cond: (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=6780919 read=48763, temp read=11359 written=11353
                                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=22756.56..501828.29 rows=10683 width=140) (actual time=1121.277..5826.907 rows=12333 loops=3)
                                       Hash Cond: (s_1.starelid = c.oid)
                                       Join Filter: has_column_privilege(c.oid, a.attnum, 'select'::text)
                                       Rows Removed by Join Filter: 266947
                                       Buffers: shared hit=6780817 read=48763, temp read=11359 written=11353
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..462367.09 rows=416791 width=82) (actual time=0.061..2480.113 rows=279280 loops=3)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=3354232 read=48763
                                             ->  Parallel Seq Scan on pg_statistic s_1  (cost=0.00..53955.73 rows=236437 width=14) (actual time=0.030..405.942 rows=279280 loops=3)
                                                   Filter: (NOT stainherit)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=464 read=48763
                                             ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a  (cost=0.43..3.02 rows=2 width=70) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=837840)
                                                   Index Cond: ((attrelid = s_1.starelid) AND (attnum = s_1.staattnum))
                                                   Filter: (NOT attisdropped)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=3353768
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=14050.06..14050.06 rows=359445 width=72) (actual time=1118.810..1118.811 rows=366932 loops=3)
                                             Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 20667kB
                                             Buffers: shared hit=28671, temp written=6186
                                             ->  Seq Scan on pg_class c  (cost=0.00..14050.06 rows=359445 width=72) (actual time=0.007..551.732 rows=366932 loops=3)
                                                   Filter: ((NOT relrowsecurity) OR (NOT row_security_active(oid)))
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=28671
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=58.42..58.42 rows=2442 width=68) (actual time=5.839..5.840 rows=2393 loops=3)
                                       Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 266kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=102
                                       ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace n  (cost=0.00..58.42 rows=2442 width=68) (actual time=0.017..2.882 rows=2393 loops=3)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=102
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=1104.73..1104.74 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1.149..1.150 rows=1 loops=96069)
           Buffers: shared hit=74601882 read=290333
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.56..1104.72 rows=1 width=401) (actual time=1.144..1.147 rows=0 loops=96069)
                 Join Filter: (c_1.oid = s_2.starelid)
                 Buffers: shared hit=74601882 read=290333
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..1103.30 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=1.141..1.143 rows=0 loops=96069)
                       Buffers: shared hit=74440049 read=284290
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..16.75 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.181..0.356 rows=1 loops=96069)
                             Join Filter: (c_1.relnamespace = n_1.oid)
                             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 57
                             Buffers: shared hit=19268934 read=1187
                             ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class c_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.069 rows=58 loops=96069)
                                   Index Cond: (relname = tbl.relname)
                                   Filter: ((NOT relrowsecurity) OR (NOT row_security_active(oid)))
                                   Buffers: shared hit=2617035 read=1168
                             ->  Index Scan using pg_namespace_nspname_index on pg_namespace n_1  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=5531986)
                                   Index Cond: (nspname = ns.nspname)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=16651899 read=19
                       ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a_1  (cost=0.43..1084.53 rows=201 width=6) (actual time=0.782..0.782 rows=0 loops=96069)
                             Index Cond: (attrelid = c_1.oid)
                             Filter: ((NOT attisdropped) AND has_column_privilege(c_1.oid, attnum, 'select'::text))
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 144
                             Buffers: shared hit=55171115 read=283103
                 ->  Index Scan using pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index on pg_statistic s_2  (cost=0.43..1.07 rows=28 width=6) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=43518)
                       Index Cond: ((starelid = a_1.attrelid) AND (staattnum = a_1.attnum))
                       Filter: (stanullfrac <> '0'::double precision)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                       Buffers: shared hit=161833 read=6043
 Planning time: 3.341 ms
 Execution time: 397056.086 ms
(103 rows)
```

And here is the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` on the "fast" server:

```
                                                                                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=18339.88..841921.77 rows=13555 width=188) (actual time=1379.248..8600.924 rows=2694 loops=1)
   Group Key: ns.nspname, tbl.relname, CASE WHEN ("substring"(split_part(version(), ' '::text, 2), '#\"[0-9]+.[0-9]+#\"%'::text, '#'::text) = ANY ('{8.0,8.1,8.2}'::text[])) THEN 27 ELSE 23 END, CASE WHEN ((version() ~ 'mingw32'::text) OR (version() ~ '64-bit'::text)) THEN 8 ELSE 4 END, $0
   Buffers: shared hit=3648911
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=18339.86..18764.78 rows=13555 width=176) (actual time=1372.967..2097.150 rows=55107 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((ns.nspname = s.schemaname) AND (tbl.relname = s.tablename) AND (att.attname = s.attname))
         Buffers: shared hit=262164
         ->  Sort  (cost=5887.15..5921.04 rows=13555 width=192) (actual time=371.212..415.656 rows=55107 loops=1)
               Sort Key: ns.nspname, tbl.relname, att.attname
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 16174kB
               Buffers: shared hit=3056
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=708.49..4956.84 rows=13555 width=192) (actual time=9.314..282.912 rows=55107 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (tbl.relnamespace = ns.oid)
                     Buffers: shared hit=3056
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=670.68..4883.30 rows=13555 width=132) (actual time=7.529..194.704 rows=55107 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (att.attrelid = tbl.oid)
                           Buffers: shared hit=3038
                           ->  Seq Scan on pg_attribute att  (cost=0.00..4007.49 rows=78125 width=68) (actual time=0.004..77.499 rows=82849 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (attnum > 0)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 37659
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2595
                           ->  Hash  (cost=637.01..637.01 rows=2693 width=72) (actual time=7.497..7.497 rows=2694 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 306kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=443
                                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_class tbl  (cost=0.00..637.01 rows=2693 width=72) (actual time=0.007..5.110 rows=2694 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (relkind = 'r'::"char")
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 12831
                                       Buffers: shared hit=443
                     ->  Hash  (cost=25.14..25.14 rows=1014 width=68) (actual time=1.757..1.758 rows=1036 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 118kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=15
                           ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace ns  (cost=0.00..25.14 rows=1014 width=68) (actual time=0.008..0.841 rows=1036 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=15
         ->  Sort  (cost=12452.71..12453.04 rows=131 width=200) (actual time=1001.404..1031.723 rows=36997 loops=1)
               Sort Key: s.schemaname, s.tablename, s.attname
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 11364kB
               Buffers: shared hit=259108
               ->  Subquery Scan on s  (cost=5455.47..12448.10 rows=131 width=200) (actual time=709.076..941.593 rows=36997 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=259108
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=5455.47..12446.79 rows=131 width=401) (actual time=709.073..886.682 rows=36997 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
                           Buffers: shared hit=259108
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=5417.65..12408.63 rows=131 width=140) (actual time=707.296..823.908 rows=36997 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: ((s_1.starelid = c.oid) AND (s_1.staattnum = a.attnum))
                                 Buffers: shared hit=259093
                                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_statistic s_1  (cost=0.00..6793.45 rows=19622 width=14) (actual time=0.014..45.484 rows=45420 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (NOT stainherit)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=6401
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=4852.66..4852.66 rows=37666 width=142) (actual time=706.898..706.899 rows=69779 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 131072 (originally 65536)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 12881kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=252689
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=831.03..4852.66 rows=37666 width=142) (actual time=29.082..629.863 rows=69779 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: (a.attrelid = c.oid)
                                             Join Filter: has_column_privilege(c.oid, a.attnum, 'select'::text)
                                             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 50729
                                             Buffers: shared hit=252689
                                             ->  Seq Scan on pg_attribute a  (cost=0.00..3724.99 rows=112999 width=70) (actual time=0.005..117.968 rows=120508 loops=1)
                                                   Filter: (NOT attisdropped)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=2595
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=637.01..637.01 rows=15521 width=72) (actual time=28.956..28.957 rows=15525 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1705kB
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=443
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on pg_class c  (cost=0.00..637.01 rows=15521 width=72) (actual time=0.007..15.192 rows=15525 loops=1)
                                                         Filter: ((NOT relrowsecurity) OR (NOT row_security_active(oid)))
                                                         Buffers: shared hit=443
                           ->  Hash  (cost=25.14..25.14 rows=1014 width=68) (actual time=1.760..1.761 rows=1036 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 118kB
                                 Buffers: shared hit=15
                                 ->  Seq Scan on pg_namespace n  (cost=0.00..25.14 rows=1014 width=68) (actual time=0.012..0.858 rows=1036 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=15
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=60.64..60.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.376..2.377 rows=1 loops=2694)
           Buffers: shared hit=3386747
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.39..60.63 rows=1 width=401) (actual time=2.280..2.369 rows=6 loops=2694)
                 Join Filter: (c_1.oid = s_2.starelid)
                 Buffers: shared hit=3386747
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.10..60.06 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=2.228..2.283 rows=16 loops=2694)
                       Buffers: shared hit=3262332
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.69..16.73 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.108..2.211 rows=1 loops=2694)
                             Join Filter: (c_1.relnamespace = n_1.oid)
                             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 364
                             Buffers: shared hit=3247620
                             ->  Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class c_1  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.398 rows=365 loops=2694)
                                   Index Cond: (relname = tbl.relname)
                                   Filter: ((NOT relrowsecurity) OR (NOT row_security_active(oid)))
                                   Buffers: shared hit=290274
                             ->  Index Scan using pg_namespace_nspname_index on pg_namespace n_1  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=983801)
                                   Index Cond: (nspname = ns.nspname)
                                   Buffers: shared hit=2957346
                       ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a_1  (cost=0.42..43.29 rows=4 width=6) (actual time=0.019..0.045 rows=16 loops=2694)
                             Index Cond: (attrelid = c_1.oid)
                             Filter: ((NOT attisdropped) AND has_column_privilege(c_1.oid, attnum, 'select'::text))
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 10
                             Buffers: shared hit=14712
                 ->  Index Scan using pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index on pg_statistic s_2  (cost=0.29..0.55 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=43518)
                       Index Cond: ((starelid = a_1.attrelid) AND (staattnum = a_1.attnum))
                       Filter: (stanullfrac <> '0'::double precision)
                       Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                       Buffers: shared hit=124415
 Planning time: 4.337 ms
 Execution time: 8605.391 ms
(102 rows)
```

Comment: I would start by taking the query from `check_postgres` and running it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see what makes it so slow. The number of entries in `pg_stats` is not a sign of bloat, it is a sign that you have way too many tables with way too many columns.

Comment: "The pg_stats table contains ~815,000 entries on the slow server."  How did you determine this?  Are you looking at just visible entries, or all tuples live and dead?

Comment: Do you have any long-running statements, or any 'idle in transaction' transactions open (as shown in pg_stat_activity)?

Comment: No statements at all were running besides the "check_bloat" query that's taking 24-30 minutes. I determined the number of entries in the pg_stats table with a simple `select count(*) from pg_stats;`.

Comment: I have the exact same number of tables on both servers. What might be different are the number of schema...

Comment: Can anyone help with this? I'm still stuck here.

Comment: I've added the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` as requested. I'm not sure it gives any more information other than what I previously indicated (the tables being queried differ drastically in size), but any insights would be appreciated. The sizes of the tables being queried are drastically different. clearly. What I'd like to is "Why are the pg_* tables so much larger on the one server compared to the other?" and "How do I fix this?" Preferably other than wiping out the PostgreSQL installation and re-ingesting all the databases and tables from scratch....

Comment: Found some information around that says select pg_stat_reset() in more recent versions only resets the statistics for the currently active database, not the entire server. Maybe you could try executing it in each database?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I executed `select pg_stat_reset();` in all databases. The query still takes a very long time on the one server. It's been over a month since I originally posted this question, and the number of entries in pg_stats has increased from ~815,000 to ~838,000 as of today. And, yes, this is after executing `select pg_stat_reset();` in all databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, mystery solved. Thanks to the above comments, I saw that the EXPLAIN output indicated that pg_attribute was also much larger than I expected. Once I looked at that, I saw what the problem was. One of our developers had a runaway process which had created over a hundred thousand tables which were supposed to be temporary but weren't and then "forgot" to clean them up. They were in a non-public schema, so I didn't notice them until now. Once I dropped these hundred thousand or so tables and executed `vacuum full pg_attribute` and `vacuum full pg_class` and `vacuum full pg_statistic`, the problem I had been having with the Nagios bloat query was finally resolved.